# get id of calendar div on clicking next/prev button in calendar in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, calendar

I have showed multiple calendars on my page using jquery UI. The calendars are working fine. I am trying to get the ID of the calendar when i click on next or previous button on the calendar. The code i am using is this:

```
<div class="calendar" id="calendar1"></div> 
<div class="calendar"id="calendar2"></div> 
<div class="calendar" id="calendar3"></div>
```

and jquery code is

```
$('.calendar').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-next', function () {
  console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id'));
});
```

it should show calendar1/calendar2/calendar3 but instead on displaying id it shows undefined. The datepicker html is this

```
<div class="calendar hasDatepicker" id="calendar1">
  <div class="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="display: block;">
    <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
      <a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" onclick="DP_jQuery_1488149175514.datepicker._adjustDate('#calendar50', -1, 'M');" title="Prev">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span>
      </a>
      <a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" onclick="DP_jQuery_1488149175514.datepicker._adjustDate('#calendar50', +1, 'M');" title="Next">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span>
      </a>
```

as we can see the parent call is correct and it is working if i use

```
console.log($('.ui-datepicker-next').parent().parent().parent().attr('id'));
```

but that will always give the id of first div ie calendar1.

Comment: The problem will be in the multiple chaining of `parent()`. I can't actually see where exactly `.ui-datepicker-next` is getting dynamically built, but it's wroth noting that it creates a div **separate** to the input. You'll need to chain a `find()` to target the input field, before getting the ID. It should still be returning **some** ID though, so I'm guessing you may have used too many parent selectors. Try first logging `$(this)`, and then work up the chain from there :)

Comment: can u add more of ur html? mostly i mean parts including `ui-datepicker-next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the Docs its: `onChangeMonthYear( Integer year, Integer month, Object inst )`

```
onChangeMonthYear:function(year, month, instance){

    console.log(instance.id)

}
```

So try using:

```
$('.calendar').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    onChangeMonthYear:function(year, month, instance){

        console.log(instance.id)

    }
});
```